# Flask: Route path that cointains "/" in variable section

Tags: flask, routes

I got into an issue in one of my flask routes path. And the reason is because I have a variable section to query that includes "/" in its name, and hence the route function will only get a part of it. Example:

localhost:5000/tables/table/1

so "table/1" is the name of the variable section, but the route function only gets the "table" part of the URL.

Is there any way to go around this?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way around this is to use a query string. Instead of

```
/tables/table/1
```

pass

```
/tables&t=table/1
```

(or some key name that's more appropriate than `t`)

Then

```
request.args.get('t')
```

will get you 'table/1' if 't' is present.